# Load links in a CSS frame?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using [this script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm) to load pages in a css frame (div#maincontent). I want the links in the loaded pages to load in this frame instead of just "going" there. I want to do this using jquery. Here is my attempt:

```
$('#maincontent a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ajaxpage($(this).attr("href"), 'maincontent');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what ajaxpage is, but if you're just loading a page into a div you can simply use [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Something like this:

```
$('#maincontent a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#maincontent").load($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

---

Edit:
If you want the loaded page to have event handlers for click too, you can use load()'s callback function for this. Like this:

```
function engageLinks() {            
    $('#maincontent a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#maincontent").load($(this).attr("href"), function() {                
            engageLinks();              
        } );
    });
}
  // Call the function the very first time the page is loaded.
  // After that the function will call itself.
engageLinks();
```

[Here's an example.](http://peter-ajtai.com/examples/js/load.php)

Comment: That works on the start page, but after loading another page in the content area, the links just "go there". How can I fix this?

Comment: @Zephlon - Added it in to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ajaxpage` with  `$('#maincontent').load($(this).attr("href"))`;